# Why "the terms of a sequence" are finite implies there is an infinitely repeated value

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

> Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence, if the set $$S=\{u_n | n\in \mathbb N\}$$ is finite that means that there is a term $u'$ such as $u_n = u'$ for infinitely many integers.

It is not completely clear for me (even though I understand the result), do you have a proof (or a sketch of proof) of it?

PS: the only way of proving it I see is to start with the negation, i.e. $S$ is infinite and hence, $S \sim \mathbb N$

Comment: A finite union of finite sets if finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your PS correctly, it is mistaken. You seem to attempt a proof by contradiction. If so, what you must assume is that $S$ is finite but that no value is taken infinitely often. I.e.
$$\forall s\in S\quad F_s:=\{n\in\Bbb N\mid u_n=s\}\text{ is finite.}$$
But then,
$$\Bbb N=\cup_{s\in S}F_s\text{ would be finite}$$
(as a finite union of finite sets), a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it via contradiction.

First, since there are only finitely many distinct values in the set, there must be a maximal value $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, assume that every value from 1 to $N$ appears finitely many times. Then if $m_i$ is the number of times $i$ appears in the sequence, there must be a maximal number of appearances $M = \max {m_i}$, so $m_i \leq M$ for all $i \leq N$.

But that means that the total number of terms in the sequence is no more than $N \times M$, since that would represent every possible value repeating the maximum number of times, and that's only finitely many terms whereas the sequence has infinitely many, which is a contradiction.

Hence there must be a value that appears infinitely often.

Comment: "there must be a maximal value $N \in \mathbb{N}$": no, the sequence is not assumed to take its values in $\Bbb N.$ The set $S$ can even be *a priori* unordered.

Comment: That's true, so I suppose it would be more correct to argue on the size of the set of values, which is known to be finite.

Comment: Or just take $\sum_{s\in S}m_s$ as an upper bound instead of $MN.$